# Not to protest, but -

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> On roaming paths I put a break,
>
> A nation's dream, I fill its shape;
>
> A rascal's drudging work I take,
>
> And all my kind, good neighbors make.

What am I?

Comment: Please. Dont tell me the answer is Hong Kong people.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you are

> a FENCE.

```
On roaming paths I put a break,
```

> (Literally.)

```
A nation's dream, I fill its shape;
```

> I didn't understand this line at all, but in comments tmpearce makes the very plausible suggestion that the line refers to "the American Dream", in its incarnation as a suburban house and garden surrounded by a white picket fence.

```
A rascal's drudging work I take,
```

> My original interpretation: A fence is a receiver (and seller) of stolen goods. The rascal is a thief. (Not sure I'd exactly call theft "drudging", though maybe it is.) Darrel Hoffman's much better interpretation, in comments: This is a reference to Mark Twain's story of Tom Sawyer tricking his friends into painting a fence for him.

```
And all my kind, good neighbors make.
```

> "Good fences make good neighbours."

The title -- "Not to protest, but -" -- refers, I think, to

> *picket* fences.

Credit where due:

> tmpearce figured out the "American Dream" bit (for which I didn't have any good ideas); Darrel Hoffman figured out the Tom Sawyer bit (for which my alternative interpretation is, I think, kinda OK though clearly inferior).

Comment: For line 2, I suspect it has to do with rot13(Gur "Nzrevpna Qernz" naq "juvgr cvpxrg sraprf" - uggcf://jjj.fzvgufbavnaznt.pbz/uvfgbel/uvfgbel-juvgr-cvpxrg-srapr-180971635/) but I don't quite understand the precise wording of the clue, perhaps it is more nuanced than I'm appreciating

Comment: Ah, that's quite possible.

Comment: rot13(Qhevat gur gjragvrgu praghel, gur Nzrevpna Qernz jnf fgebatyl gvrq gb ynaq bjarefuvc naq ubzr bjarefuvc. Fb V nz snveyl pregnva guvf vf pbeerpg.)

Comment: Not sure whether or not to upvote this answer...really can't make up my mind at all... going back and forth in my head...both sides have value. Definitely on the -----.

Comment: I unmarked this as the answer -- it's not exactly right, though very close -- however, unless you get this *exactly* right the second and third line will not make any sense.

Comment: Is the third clue a reference to rot13(Gbz Fnjlre)?

Comment: Ohhhh! Yes, it must be. Will edit.

Comment: It could also be a wall, and america's supposed 'build a wall' thing.

Comment: I wondered about that but didn't (and don't) find it convincing. I think tmpearce's suggestion has to be right, and indeed the setter has since confirmed it (in a comment they've now deleted).

Comment: @jacksonh, is it still not-quite-right after incorporating Darrel's explanation of the third line?